yup Schema Issue in Config driven UI forms React formik
I have a Config driven UI Form in react using formik. Now, I am fetching the JSON to create the form and schema in real time.
I have managed to set the schema for normal fields but when I'm trying to set the schema for dependent fields i.e. it depends on the value of other fields(name it as parent), it is not working as expected.
const getDynamicSchema = (dynamicForm, parent) => {
    let dynamicSchema = {};

    dynamicForm?.forms?.forEach((formGroup) => {
      Object.values(formGroup?.fields)?.forEach((field) => {
        let fieldSchema = null;

        switch (field?.inputType) {
          case 'string':
            fieldSchema = getDynamicStrValidations(field);
            break;
          case 'number':
            fieldSchema = string()
              .trim()
              .matches(/^\d+$/, 'Cannot be a decimal number')
              .matches('^[1-9]', 'Cannot be 0 or less than 0');
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        if (field?.validations?.required) {
          if (!field?.isConditional) {
            fieldSchema = fieldSchema.required(`${field.label} is required`);
          } else {

//Issue is mainly in this condition

            fieldSchema = fieldSchema.when([], {
              is: () => checkCondition(field?.condition, parent, values),
              then: string().required(`${field.label} is required`),
            });
          }
        }

        dynamicSchema[field?.fieldName] = fieldSchema;

        if (Object.keys(field?.isDependent || {})?.length > 0) {
          dynamicSchema = {
            ...dynamicSchema,
            ...getDynamicSchema(field?.isDependent, field?.fieldName),
          };
        }
      });
    });
    return dynamicSchema;
  };

I did try to implement it using mutiple ways but it didn;t work. Expectation is that if certain conditions are fulfilled that is the parent condition gets matched it should set my field as required.
checkCondition() returns true or false.
